# ¿Cómo puedo enviar una notificación push (firebase) sin la consola, cuando cambio un dato de la base de datos?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Estoy tratando de hacer un Chat de 2 personas y guardo los mensajes en la Base de datos de FireBase, quiero que cuando un usuario escriba el mensaje se le envíe una notificación al otro.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mensajeRef= ref.child("mensaje");
```

Ahí guardo los mensajes, tengo hecha la clase 'FirebaseMessagingService' pero solo puedo enviar notificaciones desde la consola de Firebase.

Comment: cuando hablas de consola me imagino que no tienes confeccionado el proyecto como ejecutable... cuando lo crees, puedes ejecutarlo a continuación de la función que inserta en la tabla

Comment: hablo de la consola de Firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasta donde tengo entendido si quieres envíar notificaciones desde un lugar ajeno a la consola de Firebase debes tener un servidor que se encargue de enviar una solicitud a Firebase para enviar el mensaje.

Indagando por la web encontré [este enlace](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html) que explica cómo hacer una llamada a Firebase desde un dispositivo Android con Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Acá encontré un tutorial muy útil https://www.coursera.org/learn/aplicaciones-android/lecture/Se1Fb/notificaciones-en-android

Answer (score 0):

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.enviarNotificacion = functions.database.ref('LA RUTUA DE TU BASE DE DATO')
.onWrite(async (change, context) => {

 const myId = context.params.keyid;
  const id_hora = context.params.RefTelB;
  const id_nombre = context.params.keynombre;

  if (!change.after.val()) {
    return console.log('nose', myId, 'un-followed user', id_nombre);
  }
  console.log('tines un nuevo siguidor:', 'otroMas', 'for user:', id_nombre);

  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
      .ref('RUTA DE LOS TOKEN').once('value'); ////tabla donde 

 
  let tokensSnapshot;
  let tokens;

  const results = await Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise]);
  tokensSnapshot = results[0];
  if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
    return console.log('No hay tokens de notificación para enviar.');
  }
  console.log('existen', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'este token te a enviado una notificacion.');
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: `Nuevo msj!  ${id_hora}`,
      body: `${id_nombre} esta solicitando tu ayuda.`,
     // icon: follower.photoURL
    }
  };

  tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
  const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
  response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
    const error = result.error;
    if (error) {
      console.error('error a enviar la notificacion a', tokens[index], error);
     
      if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
          error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
       
      }
    }
  });

});
```